# AutoCompleteTextView brings null pointer exception

Tags: java, arrays, android-studio, nullpointerexception, autocompletetextview

My android app has an AutoCompleteTextView in the activity_main.xml file with an ID "nameACTV". In the MainActivity.java file, when I try to write AutoCompleteTextView auto=findViewById(R.id.nameACTV) it shows red. When I try to set an adapter to the AutoCompleteTextView, as adapter=new AdapterView() auto.setAdapter(adapter); it says null; What's wrong?

I were trying to show some results as listview in the AutoCompleteTextView when the user types something. The listview will use a single line spinner layout and collect data from a StringArray inside the strings.xml file.

Comment: Can you share the layout file and your activity's onCreate() code?

Comment: **Here is the code of layout:** `<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoComplete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:background="#bf7f7f"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/auto_hint"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:textColor="#4c3333"
        tools:ignore="VisualLintTextFieldSize" />`

Comment: **Here is the onCreate() method:** `@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        autoView = findViewById(R.id.autoComplete);
        songAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.spinner, names);
        autoView.setAdapter(songAdapter);
        autoView.setThreshold(1);`